# Redis Failover - Automatic failover

Tags: redis

I have 2 redis servers setup in a master/slave configuration that looks like this:

Data Center 1:
VM (001) = 1 Master Redis + Sentinel,
VM (002) = Sentinel

Data Center 2:
VM (003) = 1 Slave Redis + Sentinel

quorum = 2 for sentinels.

When servers 001 and 002 go down, the 003 sentinel does not do a failover since the quorum is not met - 1 sentinel is up. I'm trying to take into account Data Center 1 going down or one of the sentinels going down. My question is, what do I need to change in my design for this work to correctly for automatic failover?

Comment: You need more sentinels

Comment: The issue will still exist by adding sentinels onto either of those data centers. The only option seems to put the third sentinel in a third data center.

Comment: If he had 2 sentinels in each DC and one dc went down, the sentinels in the other dc would failover. the problem would be if both dc's stayed up but lost connection to each other, both dcs would failover to themselves

Comment: In Redis Sentinel documentation it states that you have to have a majority sentinel consensus to authorize the failover.  With 2 sentinels in each DC how would they obtain a majority consensus if one of the DCs were to go down.

Comment: Ahh I thought the quorum also decided the number need to failover, but it doesn't